# SARIMAX model fitting too slow in statsmodels

Tags: time-series, statsmodels, grid-search

I am trying a grid search to perform model selection by fitting SARIMAX(p, d, q)x(P, D, Q, s) models using `SARIMAX()` method in statsmodels. I do set `d` and `D` to 1 and `s` to 7 and iterate over values of `p` in `{0, 1}`, `q` in `{0, 1, 2}`, `P` in `{0, 1}`, `Q` in `{0, 1}`, and `trend` in `{None, 'c'}`, which makes for a total of 48 iterations. During the model fitting phase, if any combination of the parameters leads to a non-stationary or non-invertible model, I move to the next combination of parameters.

I have a set of time-series, each one representing the performance of an agent over time and consisting of 83 (daily) measurements with a weekly seasonality. I keep 90% of the data for model fitting, and the last 10% for forecasting/testing purposes.

What I find is that model fitting during the grid search takes a very long time, about 11 *minutes*, for a couple of agents, whereas the same 48 iterations take much less time, less than 10 *seconds*, for others.

However, if, before performing my grid search, I log-transform the data corresponding to the agents whose analyses take a very long time, the same 48 iterations take about 15 *seconds*! However, as much as I love the speed-up factor, the final forecast turns out to be poorer compared to the case where the original (that is, not log-transformed) data was used. So, I'd rather keep the data in its original format.

My questions are the following:
What causes such slow down for certain time-serires?
And is there a way to speed-up the model fitting by giving `SARIMAX()` or `SARIMAX.fit()` certain arguments? I have tried `simple_differencing = True` which, constructing a smaller model in the state-space, reduced the time from 11 minutes to 6 minutes, but that's still too long.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: If the slowdown is only for certain time series, then they are most likely difficult to optimize. You could try to find better starting values for the optimization, i.e. `start_params`. For example, when trying different models it's often possible to warm start, by adding zeros for extra parameters or dropping parameters.

Comment: @user333700 Thanks a lot! I have tried `start_params`, by first performing a burn-in `.fit()` and then fitting the final model using `.fit(params  = <burn_in_model>.params)`. The problem is that I get a speed-up IF I set `enforce_stationarity` and `enforce_invertibility` to `False` for the burn-in phase (the final model fit is performed with these two parameters set to `True`). I don't know if (A) my final estimates are biased by not enforcing stationarity and invertiblity in the burn-in phase and if (B) the burn-in parameters would lead to the best fit possible (given the data and the model).

Comment: @user333700 But I don't quite understand the very last part of your comment, "by adding zeros for extra parameters or dropping parameters." Could you elaborate a bit please? To what exactly should I be adding zeros or which parameters should I be dropping? Maybe a one-liner example could help me. Much appreciated :)

Comment: suppose you have ARMA(1,1) and you want to estimate ARMA(2,1), then it has one additional parameter. So we could take the ARMA(1,1) parameter vector and insert a zero at the right place for the second AR coefficient. It requires to check how `params` combines the different coefficients. (I don't remember for SARIMAX)

Comment: @user333700 Ah, I see! Thank you. I went back to using the burn-in phase without enforcing stationarity and invertibility while using `simple_differencing = True`. It cut down the run time from ~ 11 minutes down to 14 seconds! The best-fit models are largely the same and have similar AICc scores. I'll stick with this for now, but will try your suggestion when I get a bit more free time to implement it. Cheers!

Comment: UPDATE: Not enforcing stationarity and invertibility within the a burn-in step sometimes leads to the optimizer not being able to find/converge to a value in the final `.fit()`. I'd get `Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.` when `method = 'bfgs'` is used, and the `nm` algorithm exceeds the maximum number of iterations.

Comment: I realise it's been more than a year, but I got the same errors as you when I tried these same two methods. I was able to get `nm` to converge by increasing the max iter to a ridiculously high value.

Comment: this library is just useless. I'll just use R for time series.

Comment: With using simple_differencing = True, Forecasts and predictions will be about the differenced data. Any work around for this @darXider ?